# c++ tool for visualising memory alignment?

Tags: c++, visualization, alignment

Is there a tool, maybe a plugin for visual Studio or so, that visualizes for me the memoryalignment of my classes and structs?

thx!

Comment: What do you want visualized? The alignment *requirements* of a given class? Or how aligned the address of a specific object is? And how should it be visualized?

Comment: i mean something that creates a graphic like this :http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r9/topic/com.ibm.zos.r9.cbcpx01/cbcpg643.gif or this: http://docs.hp.com/en/B3901-90002/img/gfx12.gif for all my classes, structs and unions

Comment: Why do you need that? Sounds like you want to do mess a bit too much with the underlying bit representation of your classes.

Comment: yes i like to do so. also sometimes you want to have your structs alignment optimized (depending on the order of your membervariables, the structs become larger or smaller). of course i can draw the alignment myself, but having a graphical tool for this would be more convenient

Comment: By arranging the members from largest members first to smallest members last the compiler will give you the best alignment.

Comment: how is that? I thought the compiler would just use the given order...

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in using [Cruncher#](http://msinilo.pl/blog/?p=509).

Reference: original [Maciej Sinilo blog post](http://msinilo.pl/blog/?p=425) about Cruncher#.

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't apply to windows, the Linux tool [PaHole](http://lwn.net/Articles/206805/), part of the 'dwarves' package on common Linux distributions, provides structure and class alignement information based on the DWARF2 debug information in ELF files.

Answer (score 0):

It is embedded into Visual Studio Debugger. It's called "Watch". You can see the address of each item if you "+" some class instance name.

Comment: hey and thanks!
I don't want to see the adresses, i'd like to see a nice graphic

Comment: Then no, there's no such a tool. Or you can write "#pragma pack(push, 1)" and draw yourself a pretty straight line.

Comment: hm. is my request not comprehensible? i think such a tool would be quite convenient

Comment: I don't think the tool would provide anything useful.